# pandas reading a csv with decimal separator comma is not changing all values

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file with a column KG and it is specified with a decimal separator as ","(comma).

```
KG
267,890
458,987
125,888
1,55
2,66
```

When I use `pd.read_csv(file_name,sep=';', decimal=",")`, only the values 1,55 and 2,66 are converted to 1.55 and 2.66 respectively.
the vales with 3 digits before the comma stay the same.

This is the **output**

```
KG
267,890
458,987
125,888
1.55
2.66
```

Please can someone guide me through how to change all values to have a dot, as well to **use dtype as float64 for the column**

Comment: it works fine on my end along with dtype of `float64`

Comment: which version of python are you using? and could you please post your code which you tried here?

Comment: i used the same code which you have mentioned above and my pandas version is `0.24.1`

Answer (score 1):

It Worked fine for me. I wrote the same code and worked.

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("/Users/SO/Desktop/test.csv",sep=';', decimal=",")
>>> df
       KG,
0  267.890
1  458.987
2  125.888
3    1.550
4    2.660
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution helped me, though I don't understand why I did not get the other way working

```
f = lambda x: (x.replace(",",".")) 
input_df = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=";",converters = {'KG':f})
```

Thanks

Comment: which pandas version do you have?

Answer (score 0):

The decimal parameter should generally be our friend here. It might be the case that the engine used does not support the decimal parameter correctly.

> engine{'c', 'python', 'pyarrow'}
>
> Parser engine to use. The C and pyarrow engines are faster, while the python engine is currently more feature-complete. Multithreading
> is currently only supported by the pyarrow engine.

To get around this, you might try to force the use of the **python engine**. Adding the desired data type for the column, this might be worth a try:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';', decimal=',', engine='python', dtype={'KG': np.float64})
```

In my case this helped.